Issue with Web Scraping: 404 Not Found when sending POST request
I'm trying to learn about Web Scraping, and I'm currently using my university's website to extract specific tables based on a code. I'm at the stage where a function acts as a "user," sending the necessary inputs so that when the "Search" button is clicked, it returns the corresponding table.
Here is the code I'm using:
import requests

# URL of the page
url = "https://www.ssa.ingenieria.unam.mx/horarios.html"

# Function to send the POST request
def get_html_response(clave):
    payload = {
        'optHorarioAsignatura': 'clave',
        'clave': clave
    }
    response = requests.post(url, data=payload)
    return response.text

# Example usage of the function
print(get_html_response("1858"))


However, when I run this code, I always get the following response:
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>

I'm not sure if there's a solution to this or what advice you could offer to achieve this task. Is it possible that I'm sending the data incorrectly? Do I need to add any additional headers to the request? I would greatly appreciate your help.

Are you sure the url path /horarios.html actually exists on the server, and is accessible via a POST reuqest?

yea, you are posting to the wrong url, the site actually does not post anything, you can get the result for 1858 by making a GET request to this url : https://www.ssa.ingenieria.unam.mx/cj/tmp/programacion_horarios/1858.html

@GTK Wooow, how did you get that link? I'm new to this topic, but it has really worked for me. Do you think you could recommend me some resources to study this topic a bit more?

the network tab is your friend, really everything is available in the devtools (F12)
